# how to use collapse plugin?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have used the collapse plugin to toggle data when it's clicked, but I am unable to do. So here is my code.I have imported the bootstrap file, do I have to use something else? I want to use the collapse in table I have searched on the internet and tried many things but nothing works

```
   <body>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
                   href="#collapseOne">
                   Click me to exapand. Click me again to collapse.
                   Section 1--hide method
                </a>
             </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
             <div class="panel-body">
              1 st collapse
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
                   href="#collapseTwo">
                   Click me to exapand. Click me again to collapse.
                   Section 2--show method
                </a>
             </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
             <div class="panel-body">
                 2 st collapse
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
                   href="#collapseThree">
                   Click me to exapand. Click me again to collapse.
                   Section 3--toggle method
                </a>
             </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
             <div class="panel-body">
               3 rd collapse
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>

          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () { $('#collapseFour').collapse({
          toggle: false
       })});
       $(function () { $('#collapseTwo').collapse('show')});
       $(function () { $('#collapseThree').collapse('toggle')});
       $(function () { $('#collapseOne').collapse('hide')});
    </script> 
    <body>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
                   href="#collapseOne">
                   Click me to exapand. Click me again to collapse.
                   Section 1--hide method
                </a>
             </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
             <div class="panel-body">
                1st collapse
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
                   href="#collapseTwo">
                   Click me to exapand. Click me again to collapse.
                   Section 2--show method
                </a>
             </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
             <div class="panel-body">
               2nd collapse
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
                   href="#collapseThree">
                   Click me to exapand. Click me again to collapse.
                   Section 3--toggle method
                </a>
             </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
             <div class="panel-body">
                3rd collapse
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>

          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () { $('#collapseFour').collapse({
          toggle: false
       })});
       $(function () { $('#collapseTwo').collapse('show')});
       $(function () { $('#collapseThree').collapse('toggle')});
       $(function () { $('#collapseOne').collapse('hide')});
    </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working correctly... where is the problem?

Comment: put `data-target` attribute in a tag that is id of target div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code (after deleting the repeated `<body>`) in a MVC application View and it worked fine, as well as in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rw78zxrp/) .
make sure that all the libraries needed are included and that jquery library is loaded before the bootstrap(js) library. 
hope this helps.

check the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rw78zxrp/) (external resources) for the structure of libraries, you can also find it [here](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=accordion)

Comment: can you tell me the structure in which I should include the library

Comment: I edited my answer to include what you've asked for.

Answer (score 0):

First Problem comes from your HTML, You open a body tag twice...

Then, check your closing tags, (too many div closing tags compared to the amount of opened divs...)

Looks like you pasted your code twice in the same box... with extra mistakes...

and then, you come to something like this :

http://www.bootply.com/vV6VNB8Fiu

so this is... working... isn't it? ^^

hope it helps ;)

Comment: @AbdulMuqeet Check the bootply example i posted, this "collapse" thing is working isn't it? ^^

Comment: It's working on bootly but not works when i copy paste it on my machine.

Comment: So problem is somewhere in your code... maybe in your js scripts included or something...

Answer (score 0):

Simple example of collapse plugin is i have describe here,

```
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#idtocollapse">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="font-size: 14px;">
                        <i class="plusminus pull-left glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        <!--text1-->
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div id="idtocollapse" class="collapse text-left">
                    <div class="faq-answer">
                        <!--text2-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
```

as per above example when you will click on `text1` at that time `text2` will `collapse-in` and `collapse-out`.

for more demo and understanding you can visit http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse_plugin.htm

Comment: I tried it but it's not working , and when I write it on bootly it works , I don't know what is wrong with it .

Comment: I tried to run your code but it's also not working I have copy paste it .